# Код не удаляет элементы из списка

Tags: python

```
List = [1, 'tt', 'tt', 3, 5, 3, 'tt', 'tt', 'tt']
for element in List:
    if element == 'tt':
        List.remove(element)
print(List) # [1, 3, 5, 3, 'tt', 'tt']
```

**Почему одни элементы списка, равные 'tt'  удаляются, а другие НЕТ**

Comment: Ничего не понятно, приведите [mcve]

Comment: Игорь, обновлен мой ответ окончательно с двумя вариантами действий:-)

Comment: Сергей, спасибо за ответы, упростил пример, просьба поясни почему так работает,  я же просто проверяю для каждого элемента соответствие и удаляю в случае совпадения, результат ожидаем, но не тот, что по факту - откуда такая нелепица. А итератор как, я понимаю, выполнение нескольких однотипных операций в цикле (одно полное действие - одна итерация)- и что из этого я должен себе понять - не понимаю, подскажи плз, заранее спасибо!

Comment: 1) обращаться надо "@Сергей", я тут сейчас случайно вопрос увидел (а @ "зажигает" сигнал, что есть сообщение). 2) Итератор идет по порядку, считает себе элементы. И вдруг у него уже сосчитанный элемент исчезает благодаря `remove`. Весь подсчет сбивается, и он начинает удалять не то, а то и вовсе не удалять. Рассуждать о странной работе Python смысла уже нет в такой ситуации.  Надо просто действовать правильно (см.  мой ответ:-)

Comment: @Сергей, спасибо за помощь в нахождении решения, разобрался, добавил пустой список и туда добавлял результаты проверки основного списка (как ты и говорил). Однако странно, что в pythone. нет такой функции, которая бы модифицировала список на лету (ведь можно внутри функции  также создать вспомогательный список, а вернуть отфильтрованный исходный) - ну да ладно, главное все встало на место!

Comment: Игорь, 1) я же привел пример такой функции `NumbersList.pop(i)` - просто с конца надо идти. 2) Если ответ ниже был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил поставленный вопрос - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева). Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и понравилось:-)

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас `"nan"` в списке, то причина в том, что изменяли итерируемый список, идя по нему вперед. Рекомендую так тогда  - идти с конца:

```
NumbersList = ['nan', 'nan', '81207719928', '81207760124', '8127789514', '8127715401', '8127712287']

for i in range (len(NumbersList)-1, -1, -1):
    if NumbersList[i] == 'nan':
        NumbersList.pop(i)

print (NumbersList) # ['81207719928', '81207760124', '8127789514', '8127715401', '8127712287']
```

или если идти вперед, то нужен второй список:

```
NumbersList = ['nan', 'nan', '81207719928', '81207760124', '8127789514', '8127715401', '8127712287']
NewList =[]

for TelNumber in NumbersList:
    if TelNumber != 'nan':
        NewList.append(TelNumber)

print (NewList) # ['81207719928', '81207760124', '8127789514', '8127715401', '8127712287']
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил поставленный вопрос - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: Во-первых, не стоит пытаться играть в телепата и писать ответы на плохо оформленные вопросы. Во-вторых, на списке `[1, None, None, 3]` ваш код ведёт себя странно

Comment: @andreymal, иногда стоит, у половины Заказчиков так:-) И да, спасибо, я плохой тестовый пример взял, еще удивился, что отработал он. Исправил.

Comment: `NewList = [x for x in NumbersList if x != 'nan']`

Comment: @andreymal для спискового включения можно ведь и не создавать новую переменную, так тоже замечательно отработает `NumbersList = [x for x in NumberList if x != 'nan']` )

Answer (score 0):

Вот правильное решение

```
List = [1, 'tt', 'tt', 3, 5, 3, 'tt', 'tt', 'tt']
OutList = []
for element in List:
    if element != 'tt':
        OutList.append(element)
print(OutList) # [1, 3, 5, 3]
```